# Keyword, identifier, or string expected after verbatim specifier: @

Tags: asp.net

I'm having a strange problem on my pages... I have these two pages that, if you dont have them opened your application does not start...

If these two pages are closed, I get the error I describe on my title of this question.

```
  Error 1   Keyword, identifier, or string expected after verbatim specifier: @
```

and it points always to the first `line` of the `page.apsx:`

```
    <%@ Page Title="Forza - Chamados" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterAdm.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TodosChamados.aspx.cs" Inherits="Testando.TodosChamados" %>

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Relatorio.aspx.cs" Inherits="Testando.Relatorio" %>
```

What could it be ?

Comment: The syntax error might be in TodosChamados.aspx.cs

Comment: @jrummell on the `codebehind´ ? But what ? It's working fine... But this error is getting me crazy

Comment: Also check the master page and it's codebehind.

Comment: @jrummell Ok, and the second one ? It does not has a masterpage... ;s

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the full error message and your code. Have you tried to Clean and Rebuild?

Comment: @jrummell Yes I did, the full error is: `A namespace cannot directly contain, members such as fields or methods` and this appears 2x `Keyword, identifier, or string expected after verbatim specifier: @` this is the full error. There are some things I had to change on the `path` of the pages, because IIS wasn't recognizing it. I know there's a chat here in stackoverflow, could we chat therE? Then I Show you the full code...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution for my strange problem... I don't know why and I dont know wich is the difference between set a page propert `Build Action = Content / Complie`. But all I did was set them to `Content` instead of `compile` and worked like a charm !

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2090381/1919644) post.