# "The 'configuration' element is not declared" error, what does it mean?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, app-config

I have a WPF/C# application that I have created using Visual Studio 2012 to which I added a typed DataSet through the wizard.

Everything went smoothly, I could run everything over and over without any issues, until suddenly, I can't compile the solution anymore, I get the following errors inside the file App.config:

> Error  3   Unrecognized escape sequence    [...]\App.config    7   56  Contabilità Chiurlo v4
>       Warning 1   The 'configuration' element is not declared.    [...]\App.config    2   2   Contabilità Chiurlo v4
>       Error   2   A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods   [...]\App.config    1   1   Contabilità Chiurlo v4

The structure of the `App.config` file, which I have never edited manually, is the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SOME NAME" connectionString="MY CONNECTION STRING"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Where, of course, `SOME NAME` and `MY CONNECTION STRING` represents personal data, omitted for clarity.

My knowledge of this matter is close to zero, I have searched about similar issues but they all seem referred to somehow different situations. Some of them give a hint about a lack of xmlns specification, but I wouldn't know which one to add.

Looking back at my previous projects, the `App.config` file always had a similar structure, but now it is preventing me from compiling, while previously it probably only generated warnings.

What went wrong? How to fix it?

EDIT: The first error (marked as number 3), was caused by the absence of an escape character  in my connection string, that had the structure `C:\dir1\dir2` instead of `C:\\dir1\\dir2`.
However, the other two errors (marked as 1 and 2), keep arising.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching in the line and column specified in the error message for some invalid character. It points to your connection string in line 7, which you didn't provided.

Comment: I have corrected the first error, turns out backslashes had no escaping backslash (strange, considering the wizard probably generated it that way).
However, the other two errors are still unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was exactly the same one reported (and solved) at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090369/error-a-namespace-does-not-directly-contain-members-such-as-fields-or-methods).

I was just looking for the wrong keywords.

P.S. The URI `C:\dir1\dir2` was, despite what appeared, correct: there was no "`unrecognized escape sequence`", and there was no need for escape characters. The corresponding error was merely a consequence of the other error. (namely "`A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods`")